# Intersection Matrix of a resolution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, divisors, blow-ups, resolution-of-singularities

Probably this is a very easy question. Let $f:X\rightarrow S$ be a resolution of a projective surface such that
$$K_X = f^{*}K_S+\sum_ia_iE_i$$
with $a_i>0$. By Grauert-Mumford theorem the intersection matrix of the $E_i$'s is negative definite. I found the following claim: there exists an $E_j$ such that
$$E_j\cdot(\sum_ia_iE_i)<0.$$
Why is this true?

Comment: Just compute $\Bigl(\sum a_iE_i\Bigr)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can argue also in the following way (let us do the case of two componets $E_1$, $E_2$ for simplicity of notation. The general case will be clear):

the intersection matrix
$$
I = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
E_1^2 & E_1E_2 \\ 
E_1E_2 & E_2^2
\end{array}\right)
$$
is negative definite. In particular if you take the vector $a=(a_1,a_2)$ you get
$$a\cdot I\cdot a^{t} = a_1^2E_1^2+2a_1a_2E_1E_2+a_2^2E_2^2 <0.$$
On the other hand 
$$a_1^2E_1^2+2a_1a_2E_1E_2+a_2^2E_2^2 = a_1E_1(a_1E_1+a_2E_2)+a_2E_2(a_1E_1+a_2E_2)<0.$$
Since $a_1,a_2>0$ the last inequality yields either $E_1(a_1E_1+a_2E_2)<0$ or $E_2(a_1E_1+a_2E_2)<0$.